# Charge a user a fee based on gas price?

Tags: gas, nft, gas-price, fees, mint

I want to let users mint NFTs and charge them a fee for each NFT that is a percentage of the gas price they are paying to mint.

For example, if the total gas cost of minting one token is 0.1 ETH, and my fee rate is 25%, then my fee would be (0.1 ETH * 25%) = 0.025 ETH and the total cost to the user would be 0.1 ETH + 0.025 ETH = 0.125 ETH.

How can I achieve this? I suppose I would look at `tx.gasprice` and multiply that by the estimated gas cost of the minting? But then how would I get that exactly?

Comment: You could make the mint function require the price plus the fee.

Comment: @Ismael but how would I say what the fee is? Previously I've set the fee to some fixed amount of ETH and checked that against `msg.value`. In this scenario though I would need to make the fee vary based on what is in the message itself as the `msg.data` affects the overall gas price.

Comment: You have access to `gasleft()`, `tx.gasprice`, see other global variables https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html. With those you can approximate how much gas is used.